# The ' new activity ' bar in the search is not showing up anymore, is it because of the "Testing new traffic management tool"?

Tags: bug, search, live-refresh, web-sockets

Windows 11 Pro Version 21H2
Google Chrome 103.0.5060.66 64bits
Mozilla Firefox 102.0 (64-bits)
Brave 1.40.109 Chromium: 103.0.5060.66 (Official Version) 64 bits

Android 8.0.0; SM-G935F Build/R16W
Chrome 103.0.5060.53
Brave 1.40.106, Chromium 103.0.5060.53

---

[Testing new traffic management tool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418982/11462274)

I noticed that since yesterday the bar of new activities such as this one `1 question with new activity` is no longer appearing, I would like to understand the reason to know if I should mark it as a bug in [Meta](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Websocket-Indicator).

1. I've already done a complete cleaning of the saved data of the site
   in my browser and it didn't solve.
2. I have already restarted the page and the browser.
3. I've tested it in other browsers.
4. I've tested using [Websocket Indicator by CertainPerformance](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Websocket-Indicator) (WebSocket was installed after I noticed the problem → installed to test on request in a comment), so it is not the culprit of the problem), with the
   green bars but the new activities still don't appear.
5. I've been to `DevTools → Application → Storage → Clear Site Data`.

Now:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Test in [Real-Time Web Test](https://websocketstest.com/):

[image]

Comment: Works just fine for me

Comment: What URL are you expecting to see the new activity bar under? It's not enabled for all pages. Otherwise, it could also be that the websocket connection you had closed - try refreshing the page

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance this is my custom filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-formula+or+python+or+google-apps-script+or+google-sheets?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers&uqlId=60812

Comment: when i opened that link, it showed a new activity bar within a few seconds, lol

Comment: No repro - opened the link and [got the notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsuSM.png). Firefox 101 on Windows 10

Comment: @KevinB I use Chrome, I tested it in Firefox and it doesn't appear either, does the OS have something that may have blocked me from using this option? That's weird.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer "*does the OS have something that may have blocked me from using this option?*" perhaps the websockets are being closed. This could be a software issue (e.g., firewall or OS) or a hardware one (e.g., router drops the connection). You can try [this userscript by CertainPerformance](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Websocket-Indicator). I did have a similar problem on another machine and it turned out websockets were closed for some reason after some inactivity. But I have not tracked down *why*.

Comment: It is working spotty again for me. It appears, but nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: @VLAZ I took the test and the bars are green, but the new activities still don't appear.